# Casual veersus competetive dedicated servers in Counter Strike: GO

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I have just created community competitive server of CS:GO. However when I connect to it I'm not able to join any team. Does it mean that server in this mode can only be used by random people from matchmaking provided in-game?

I do not understand the difference between casual and a competitive **dedicated** server completely.

Answer (score -1):

Classic casual setup example: game_type 0 game_mode 0 mapgroup mg_active +map de_dust2
Classic competitive setup example: game_type 0 game_mode 1 mapgroup mg_active map de_dust2

If using SRCDS these need to go in to the command line options, otherwise you can specify them in the console if you have created a game through CSGO it's self.

Comment: This answers a problem OP repprts, **but does not answer the question OP asks**.